# Немого передать результат во второе View

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

Вопрос заключается в передачи результат из ViewModel в любое View

Mоя Model

```
    struct ItemsModel: Codable {
    
    var item1: String = ""
    var item2: String = ""
}
```

View

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var resultViewModel = CalcViewModel()
    @State var isResultView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Ввод значения")) {
                    TextField("Введите число", text: $resultViewModel.itemModel.item1)
                    TextField("Введите число", text: $resultViewModel.itemModel.item2)
                }
                Section (header: Text("Ответ")) {
                    Text("\(resultViewModel.resultCalc())")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.isResultView.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Рассчитать")
                })
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isResultView) {
                        ResultView()
                    }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Calculate"))
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    class CalcViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemModel = ItemsModel()
    
    var item1Double: Double {
        return Double(itemModel.item1) ?? 0
    }
    
    var item2Double: Double {
        return Double(itemModel.item2) ?? 0
    }
    
    func resultCalc() -> Double {
        
        let resultDouble = item1Double + item2Double
        print(" \(resultDouble)")
        
        return resultDouble
    }
}
```

View куда надо передать результат

```
    struct ResultView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = CalcViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ответ: \(vm.resultCalc())")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта. Попроще передавать в конструктор:

```
...
let model:CalcViewModel
...
init(model:CalcViewModel){
   self.model = model
}
...
```

второй вариант, в View в котором заполняется модель, добавляете:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Ввод значения")) {
                    TextField("Введите число", text: $resultViewModel.itemModel.item1)
                    TextField("Введите число", text: $resultViewModel.itemModel.item2)
                }
                Section (header: Text("Ответ")) {
                    Text("\(resultViewModel.resultCalc())")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.isResultView.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Рассчитать")
                })
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isResultView) {
                        ResultView()
                    }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Calculate"))
        }.environmentObject(resultViewModel)
    }
```

и там где вам нужно модель получить:

```
struct ResultView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject vm:CalcViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ответ: \(vm.resultCalc())")
    }
}
```

[вот есть пример](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) если абстрагироваться от вашего кода использование `environmentObject`:

```
// Our observable object class
class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}

// A view that expects to find a GameSettings object
// in the environment, and shows its score.
struct ScoreView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings

    var body: some View {
        Text("Score: \(settings.score)")
    }
}

// A view that creates the GameSettings object,
// and places it into the environment for the
// navigation view.
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var settings = GameSettings()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // A button that writes to the environment settings
                Button("Increase Score") {
                    settings.score += 1
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: ScoreView()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

[доки](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) по вашему вопросу и [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/527364/)

Comment: А вообще мой подход правильный или нет? Можно обойтись без Model?

Comment: можно и без модели, но на мой взгляд разбирать поля легче чем пробрасывать все по одному, это от удобства зависит